# В каком случае Вы лично ставите минус за ответ?

Tags: обсуждение

Я понимаю, что **вопрос не новый.** Минусы сейчас ставят (за ответы) не так часто, поэтому они привлекают внимание. Минус — это **знак**, а что **он означает лично для Вас?**

**Я минусы не ставлю** практически никогда, и хочу объяснить почему. Я считаю, что минуса заслуживает такой ответ, **который противоречит чему-то общеизвестному и общепринятому** (это должно объясняться и быть понятным), причем участник **упорно настаивает на своем мнении**. В этом случае знак говорит о том, что его мнение с большой вероятностью неверное, и это важно для форума.

**Объяснения сейчас, как правило, даются,** но знак минус довольно часто обозначает следующее: **ваше мнение неверно, а верно мое.** Тогда знак приобретает частный характер, а это уже не так интересно ни для форума, ни для автора вопроса.

Это в первую очередь касается **дискуссионных вопросов**, когда ни у одной из сторон нет неопровержимых доказательств.

Я, к примеру,  получаю минус за источники: за словарь Тихонова, который отличается от словаря Морковкина; за парадигму Зализняка, которую неправильно обозначили на сайте.

Другие люди получают минус за конкурсный ответ на вопрос, который **вообще нигде не изложен** и там, кроме собственного понимания грамматики, трудно что-либо предложить.

Итак, повторяю вопрос: **Вы лично за какие ответы ставите минус?**

Может быть, нужны разные знаки, например,  знак "минус особый" за явно неверную информацию.

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно согласен с каждым вашим словом. К сожалению, минусы на нашем форуме ставят только потому, что их мнение расходится с мнением другого ответчика. Один из таких случаев, связан с вами. Думаю, читающие сами поймут, о чем речь. Что касается ошибок. А кто от них не застрахован? Даже Грамота.ру ошибается. Минусы заслуживают именно те ответы, которые не просто **противоречат чему-то общеизвестному и общепринятому**, но и вообще не несут никакой информации. Иначе говоря  - отсебятина.

Но почему-то такие ответы минусы не получают.

Comment: Да, Серж, жаль, что нельзя отменить постановку неоправданного минуса технически. Или можно?  Мы же голосуем за закрытие вопросов. Может быть, и здесь применить такую процедуру. Она будет выглядеть как апелляция, которую может подать как сам "пострадавший", так и любой участник, который считает постановку минуса несправедливой. Пока этот вопрос находится в ведении модераторов, так я понимаю?  Ну и следует разработать перечень причин. Это возможно, как вы думаете?

Comment: Sharon, убрать минус можно, проголосовав за этот вопрос.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, перечень причин есть. Но вот кто его соблюдает? Ведь и мы можем минусовать ответы. Просто не делаем.

Comment: Это немного не то. Здесь важно общественное мнение, а не только мнение одного человека, да еще неизвестно кого. А так получится: проголосовали за отмену минуса такие-то участника, причина такова. Кстати, я этого перечня не видела (может, его подкорректировать надо).  Но в любом случае, даже если он существует, нужен общественный контроль за соблюдением закона. Тогда люди подумают, стоит ли ставит минус или нет, тогда  это будет ответственное решение.

Comment: Кто будет контролировать? Да и зачем все это? Все зависит от чедовека. Здесь минусы ставят пару человек всего.

Comment: Ставили раньше, да только ситуация изменилась. Появились новые люди со странными вопросами и странными ответами. Надо как-то реагировать на это, а то форум меняется на глазах и превращается в обычный чат, где каждый спрашивает что хочет и отвечает по своему разумению, озвучивая только свое собственное мнение, не нуждаясь в словарях. Это уже мешает нормальной работе, а что получится, если таких "пришельцев" будет много. Нужны строгие критерии по качеству вопросов и ответов, отсюда и необходимость в контроле. Всё это, наверное, можно организовать техническими средствами, не привлекая людей.

Comment: Да, согласен. Но я говорю о минусах тааким участникам, как мы с вами.

Comment: Мы  в этом случае тоже могли бы попасть под защиту и чувствовать себя увереннее, если бы были четкие правила и технический контроль.   Идеал - это чувство свободы в строгих рамках дозволенного, а сейчас, отвечая на вопрос, постоянно находишься под напряжением, которое можно обозначить так:  "нам не дано предугадать, как слово наше отзовется..."

Comment: Sharon, вы думаете, что помимо тех старых нескольких участников, и новые тоже ставят?

Comment: Вам же недавно поставили минус за конкурсный ответ, причем ставил весьма симпатичный  участник. Он не стал бы этого делать, если бы были  определенные правила.  Вот сейчас за вопрос о подушке отвечающему поставили два минуса. Можно было бы просто сделать замечание о необходимости более ясного указания  на связь слов, то есть ему надо было подробнее изложить свою гипотезу.

Comment: Sharon, насколько мне известно, минус поставил автор вопроса.

Comment: Ну да, я про него и говорю. Это меня как раз и удивило.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но когда минус ставит модератор... Тогда о чем говорить...

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Но, может, это было немного эмоциональное решение. Я уже привыкла всех извинять.

Comment: Здесь не должно быть эмоциальных решений. Причем ваш ответ был абсолютно верным. Думаю, от нас с вами ничего здесь не зависит.Я уже не обращаю внимание. В конце в концов, мы с вами здесь, чтобы помочь людям, да и заодно самим повысить свои знания.

Comment: Не должно, конечно. Но, обратите внимание, тема только нас интересует, поэтому вряд ли стоит надеяться на поддержку общества и на какие-то изменения в будущем.

Comment: Вы абсолютно  правы.

Answer (score 1):

Я ставлю минус, если ответ или вопрос некачественный, но соответствует правилам сообщества.

Например, вопрос по этимологии, начинающийся словами "По моему мнению...". У каждого может быть своё мнение (я и сам неоднократно его в подобных вопросах высказывал), но в вопросах этимологии и орфографии оно может иметь вес только если вопрос не имеет решения в словарях или, если знаний отвечающего хватает, чтобы эти словари дополнить.

В целом, за что ставить или не ставить минусы человек решает сам, но если минусы превращаются в способ травли, то об этом следует сообщить модераторам.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне кажется, что формулировка "ответ не является полезным" слишком неопределенная. К примеру, положительное голосование обозначает примерно одно и то же: я согласен с отвечающим, меня его ответ устраивает. А для минуса может быть целый спектр причин, нельзя ли их в правилах как-то обозначить? Кстати, где можно посмотреть требования к вопросам и ответам, они достаточно конкретны? Например,  ответ дан, но никак не объясняется. Или объясняется без ссылок на правила, если такие ссылки явно необходимы. Как обозначить свое мнение, когда для решения проблемы источников нет ?

Comment: @Sharon uолосование против означает, что в сообщении имеется неверная информация, оно плохо продумано или оно не несет полезной информации.
Требования к вопросам и ответам можно посмотреть в Справке.

К ответам - https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

К вопросам - https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Если для решения нет надёжных источников, или их надо дополнить, важно показать, что они искались. Пара примеров из моих ответов.
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17983/Первый-блин-комом

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/Почему-на-постном-масле

Comment: Вы исходите из следующего положения: "В целом, за что ставить или не ставить минусы, человек решает сам",  Таким образом, минус - это субъективное решение каждого. В принципе отчитываться за минусы никто не обязан, кто их ставит - тоже неизвестно.Требования к ответам очень общие, там нет конкретных рекомендаций, подходящих именно для нашего форума "Русский язык".

Comment: К примеру, обсуждалась этимология слова подушка. Достоверной версии нет,  Фасмер не объясняет морфемный состав слова, непонятно, что значит приставка ПО. А вдруг это действительно корень, а не приставка. И вот участник выдвигает эту собственную версию. В принципе ответ оформлен очень неудачно,  его бы подкорректировать надо, но самая идея заслуживает внимания. Есть о чем подумать, тем не менее  ответ получает два минуса.

Comment: @Sharon версия может и заслуживает внимания, но если это самостоятельное исследование, надо указать на основании чего пришли к такому выводу, логику рассуждений. Автор ответа в комментариях недвусмысленно намекнул, что раскрывать этого не собирается. Поэтому при обработке тревоги (на ответ была жалоба) я ответ оставил, но поставил минус. За что был поставлен первый минус, надо спрашивать у того кто его поставил. Мне доводилось получать минусы и за вопросы с рейтингом 8 (сейчас за него 19 плюсов и один минус)

Comment: Да, Вы правы, логику он не раскрыл, хотя мог бы, наверное. В Сети есть фотографии деревянных подушек, которые очень напоминают подставку. И в англ. языке подушка обозначается несколькими словами, среди которых есть подставка, колодка.

Comment: @МаркИз, многие ставят минусы исходя из субъективных оценок: "Мой ответ правильный, а ваш нет". Как,например,  за один из ответов Sharon поставили минус, потому что участник, поставивший минус, не был согласен с ее мнением. Между тем ответ Sharon был обоснованный, в нем были ссылки на авторитетные источники.

Comment: И что удивительно: такие, как Sharon получают минусы. А те ответы, которые заслуживают минуса( в последнее время их полно. От новых участников). И те, кто любит ставить минусы - их не минусует. Что это, если не травля?

Comment: @Серж и плохо, что не ставят минусы. Как новый участник поймёт, что его ответ плох, если сообщество промолчит. Я регулярно получаю жалобы на ответы с явно неточными сведениями. у которых нулевой или положительный рейтинг и ни одного комментария. Т. е. пожаловаться, написав модератору - запросто, хотя правила не нарушены, а потратить 2 пункта своего рейтинга - ни за что!