# <БЛОГ> Выпуск № 2: вакансия в команде сайта и кое-что из новостей

Tags: обсуждение, блог

### Приветствyю, друзья!

Надеюсь, вы счастливо проводите первые дни мая и будете не прочь прочитать второй выпуск [нашего блога](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/178412). В нём мы обсудим акутальные проблемы сайта и традиционно поделимся кое-какой статистикой. Что ж — в путь!

[image]

### 1. Присоединяйтесь к команде сайта!

Наш сайт растёт, в связи с чем значительно возрастает нагрузка на тех членов сообщества, которых зовут модераторами. Если справляться с появляющимися всё чаще и чаще тревогами ещё удаётся, то заниматься развитием сообщества становится слишком трудно. Мы бы хотели чаще устраивать разнообразные акции, которые бы оживляли сайт, делали бы участие более интересным, но для этого остаётся довольно мало сил — именно поэтому **пришло время для поиска новых членов команды**!

Вкратце опишем, чем придётся заниматься:

- тщательно изучив правила сайта, обрабатывать тревоги участников;
- принимать активное участие во внутренних и внешних обсуждениях, связанных с развитием сайта;
- предлагать и комментировать идеи конкурсов и прочих акций;
- участвовать в разработке блога сайта.

Эта позиция — волонтёрская, хотя требует немало сил. Но кто сказал, что добровольная работа не вознаграждается?! Как минимум, видеть, как растёт и процветает то, во что ты вложил частичку души, — очень приятное занятие! :)

Если вам интересно это предложение, пожалуйста, расскажите, почему вы хотите стать частью команды сайта в ответе к этому выпуску блога.

### 2. Изменения в статистике

Друзья, нужно отметить, что наш сайт взял планку в 10 вопросов за день и пока что успешно её держит, как настоящий «здоровый» член Stack Exchange.

На Мете было задано несколько интересных вопросов от участников Sharon и Galina Avanesova. Если вы их не видели, обратите на них внимание и прокомментируйте — это поможет совершенствованию правил и интерфейса сайта:

- [В каком случае Вы лично ставите минус за ответ?](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/434/178412)
- ["Но ох как хочется, чтобы давали комментарии с объяснением ошибок" (за минусование вопроса/ответа)](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/456/178412)
- [Не изменить ли требования к шапке вопроса?](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/457/178412)

### 3. Немного о планах

Текущий выпуск блога получился несколько техническим — мы надеемся исправить это уже в следующий раз, посвятив блог № 3 обсуждению того, что непосредственно связано с происходящим на сайте. Кстати, если у вас есть идеи о том, что может быть хорошей темой, напишите об этом в комментариях!

---

Итак, на сегодня всё. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на объявление о наборе в команду — это действительно важно!

Будем рады видеть любые замечания или ответные реплики под этим сообщением!

До скорых встреч!

[image]